# what do you properly delete foreign key tables with dependencies in database upon reworking schema?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-administration

I use django/rails, and if I completely change my mind about a schema and want to delete something that's referenced as a FK, if I delete that table django asks me "this will require deletion of all objects that depend on it...is that OK?"

I was wondering (besides humorous answers like use a graphdb or plan out your db better), what is the serious DBA production answer to a big change like this with working data a system uses?

You could also leave it silent and maybe run a daily script to ensure new employees don't use that model, after leaving comments above the MVC model to not use this old cruft model. This seems pretty bad longterm.

Thinking about it this morning, is it as simple as reading the schema for all tables referencing this item, and dropping the FK reference column in the many side for all those tables, and there will be no issues after that?

If this is the answer, are there any possible side effects of that? like other tables referencing those tables and running queries EXPECTING that foreign key column to be there? If so, what to do about that?

At home, I haven't been in production yet and at work we had DBA's so I'm wondering in general how the expert DBA's handle that specific thing. Thank you

Comment: What are you asking exactly? How a DBA removes a foreign key? That's a simple `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: I was wondering the proper way to reorganize a database that has a table you wanna delete if other stuff depends on it

Comment: Remove any references to that table from your code, delete the foreign key constraints, drop the foreign key columns, drop the table. Preferably in that order.